# Count number of messages per user

Tags: mysql

Consider the following tables:

```
users                messages
-----------------    -----------------------
user_id  messages    msg_id user_id content
-----------------    -----------------------
1        0           1      1       foo
2        0           2      1       bar
3        0           3      1       foobar
                     4      3       baz
                     5      3       bar
```

I want to count the number of messages per user and insert the outcome into users.messages, like this:

```
users                
-----------------    
user_id  messages    
-----------------    
1        3           
2        0           
3        2
```

I could use PHP to perform this operation, pseudo:

```
foreach ($user_id in users) {
  $count = select count(msg_id) from messages where user_id = $user_id
  update users set messages = $count
}
```

But this is probably very inefficient as compared to one query executed in MySQL directly:

```
UPDATE users SET messages = (
  SELECT COUNT(msg_id) FROM messages
)
```

But I'm sure this is not a proper query. Therefore, any help would be appreciated :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the answer:

```
UPDATE `users` AS u 
SET u.messages=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM messages WHERE user_id=u.user_id)
```

and the test:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2768b/1

I just hope these are not huge tables or this could take a while...

**UPDATE:**
Removed unnecessary JOIN from the query
Thanks to @Ariel and @Zane Bien for correcting my answer!

Comment: Why are you joining the messages table in the outer query?

Comment: @Ariel, that's exactly what I was wondering. The `LEFT JOIN` here is completely unnecessary if you're just going to update it using a correlated subquery. Furthermore, the `LEFT JOIN` makes it much more inefficient as the subquery will need to execute for ***every*** one of each user's messages instead of just once for each user. Say one of the users has 2000 messages for example, MySQL will update that user's message-count ***2000*** times with the ***same*** value, instead of just once!!

Comment: @Ariel @Zane Bien You're right! Since it seems that the default value for messages column is 0, `INNER JOIN` is enough. I used `LEFT JOIN` thinking about users with no messages, to fill their column as well. If messages contain previous data, and messages can be erased, than `LEFT JOIN` is a must, for repopulating data.

Comment: @Zagor23 No. You don't need ANY join at all, not inner, not left. The join is doing nothing, and in fact is hurting you, causing you to repeat the update FAR FAR FAR too many times.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE users JOIN
       (SELECT user_id, COUNT(msg_id) num FROM messages group by user_id) c
       USING (user_id)
SET users.messages = c.num
```

Note: I didn't test this.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL permits you to use `JOIN` operations in `UPDATE` statement like so:

```
UPDATE 
    users a
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT user_id, COUNT(1) AS messagecount
    FROM messages
    GROUP BY user_id
) b ON a.user_id = b.user_id
SET 
    a.messages = COALESCE(b.messagecount, 0)
```

What this will do is line up each corresponding user with the count of his/her messages in the `messages` table, and so updating the `messages` column becomes a simple matter of referencing the corresponding joined column containing the message count.

If a user does not have any messages in the `messages` table, it will simply set the column to `0`.

You can also be sure that this will execute very quickly as there is no need to use inefficient subqueries(which end up executing on each iteration), and also the fact that the join will be performed over indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know how to fire the query i'd say this ...

Create a trigger on insert whenever an message is posted into the messages table and insert the number of rows into the users table.  Thus you don't have to fire a query by php each time you insert a new message.  Thus your no of messages will be updated automatically whenver you insert a new message and you just have to fire a select query when you want to check the number of messages for a particular user.

[Trigger documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/triggers.html)

Answer (score 1):

This one would surely work.
Try this:

```
UPDATE users u
 SET u.messages =
      (  SELECT COUNT (*)
           FROM messages m
       GROUP BY user_id
         HAVING u.user_id = m.user_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
UPDATE users u
inner join 
(
  Select user_id, count(1) as number
    from users u inner join messages m on (u.user_id=m.user_id) group by m.user_id 
) as temp_message tm on (u.user_id=tm.user_id)
set u.messages=tm.number
```

Comment: @Ariel: have changed my query plz check